# QGIS 3.4 / QgsVectorLayer()

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I tried to use `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)` on QGIS 3.4 but I didn't succeed.

Example:

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer(r'C:\CURSO_PYQGIS\CAPAS\urbano.shp','urbano','ogr ') 
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

But the layer didn't show up, and it didn't give me an error on Python console. I don't understand it, someone knows why?

Comment: Did you check layer validity before adding it ? By doing `layer.isValid()`

Comment: There should not be a space after `ogr`. Change `'ogr '` to `'ogr'`.

Comment: Thanks Joseph!!! that was the reason "There should not be a space after ogr. Change 'ogr ' to 'ogr'"

Answer (score 1):

The format ("\" instead of "/") of the path could be the cause of your error (see the test below). *(I work on Windows and I install Qgis3 with OSGEo4)*

This is output of some test I made :

```
# Here with your format '\'
lyr_error = QgsVectorLayer(r'C:\temp\Parcelles_agricoles_5.shp', 'Parcelles agricole', 'ogr')
# Here with this format "/"
lyr_no_error = QgsVectorLayer(r'C:/temp/Parcelles agricoles_5.shp', 'Parcelles agricole', 'ogr')
# An other format that also valid
lyr_no_error2 = QgsVectorLayer('C:\\temp\\Parcelles agricoles_5.shp', 'Parcelles agricole', 'ogr')
# Test validity
lyr_error.isValid()
>>> False
lyr_no_error.isValid()
>>> True
lyr_no_error2.isValid()
>>> True
# Here it doesn't output anything even no error
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr_error)
# Here it output the instance and the layer show up.
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr_no_error)
>>> <qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x0000000009ED4D38>
```

I didn't try other type of format but this could be the solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot!,your information will help me a lot

Answer (score -1):

There are some good tutorial about QGIS Python Programming at [Geodose](https://www.geodose.com/p/pyqgis.html). Some tutorials are: Working with Vector Layer ,Add/Delete Field and Updating Attribute Value ,Adding CSV Data,Drawing Marker,Drawing,Polyline and Polygon,Animate GPS Track, Set and Reload Basemap Datasource. Quite good resource.